# You need to either use message[String], or messageText[Widget] or define a userInputForm[Form] in GetSnackbar

Tags: flutter, flutter-getx

I am new to flutter and Getx. Stood before a problem, googled it and looked for reference in youtube too but couldn't find appropriate answer.

[image: Here is the detailed error message]

It's a runtime error.

Hoping someone has the answer. Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you use a `Get.snackbar()` you have to declare two String values..

The First one is the "Title", and the second one is the "Message".

I will put an example for that, and wish that help you.

```
Get.snackbar(
        'Alert!!',
        'You have to fill all fields',
        snackPosition: SnackPosition.BOTTOM,
        duration: const Duration(seconds: 2),
        borderRadius: 13,
        backgroundColor: Colors.greenAccent,
      );
```